# XML Parsing Error: not well-formed

Tags: xml

I'm getting this parsing error below. I cannot get this to work. What is wrong?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<response>
    <user facebook_id="323" longitude="52" latitude=”25” firstname=”a” surname=”aa” profile_pic_url=”aa” />
    <user facebook_id="12" longitude=”33” latitude=”44” firstname=”Jae” surname=”Choi” profile_pic_url=”/img/files/test.jpeg” />
    <user facebook_id="444" longitude=”222” latitude=”111” firstname=”” surname=”” profile_pic_url=”” />
    <user facebook_id="222" longitude=”222” latitude=”111” firstname=”” surname=”” profile_pic_url=”” />
    <user facebook_id="221" longitude=”222” latitude=”111” firstname=”” surname=”” profile_pic_url=”” />
    <user facebook_id="121" longitude=”222” latitude=”111” firstname=”” surname=”” profile_pic_url=”” />
    <user facebook_id="421" longitude=”222” latitude=”111” firstname=”” surname=”” profile_pic_url=”” />
    <user facebook_id="33" longitude=”12” latitude=”1” firstname=”” surname=”” profile_pic_url=”” />
    <user facebook_id="22" longitude=”-37.816” latitude=”-37.811” firstname=”Jae1” surname=”Choi1” profile_pic_url=”/img/files/test1.jpeg” />
</response>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are frequently using `”` (I think that is Unicode Character 'RIGHT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK' (U+201D)) instead of `"` (Unicode Character 'QUOTATION MARK' (U+0022))

[image: This is a zoomed screenshot]

Answer (score 4):

This character looks a suspect `”`. Change them to `"` and try.

Answer (score 2):

This `”` quotes are invalid in XML. You can use single `'` or double `"` quotes.